# How do you transition content with the Polymer core-scroll-header-panel?

Tags: polymer

In the [`core-scroll-header-panel` demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html), is the Title text transition done with custom JS or with built in component controls? I was able to determine the background transition is controlled by `#headerBg` and `#condensedHeaderBg`, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get content to transition correctly with this component.